# How to subscribe to an event with a delegate

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, events, delegates, anonymous-methods

I would like to subscribe to an event so that when the event fires I can execute a delegate or anonymous function.

Subscribing to events with methods is easy I can just type the method name, this works fine:

```
UnityEngine.UI.Toggle tgl;
tgl.onValueChanged += myMethod;
```

But I cannot subscribe a delegate using the same syntax. This will not work:

```
tgl.onValueChanged += delegate{ Debug.Log("Bang!"); };
```

I researched this [Q&A](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/90694d50-92dd-4f23-af22-8ec2db6693b9/lambda-expression-in-event-handler-assignment?forum=csharpgeneral) which suggested I try the following approach but this is also not working:

```
tgl.onValueChanged += (object sender, EventArgs e) => { Debug.Log("Bang!"); };
```

How can I make this work?

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.Toggle-onValueChanged.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to look at what type `onValueChanged` is, before trying to subscribe to it. This is its declaration, taken from [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.Toggle-onValueChanged.html).

```
public UI.Toggle.ToggleEvent onValueChanged;
```

Its type is a [`ToggleEvent`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.Toggle.ToggleEvent.html), which is a class, not an event nor a delegate. Therefore, you cannot use the `+=` operator on it.

You should call `AddListener`, like the examples did:

```
tgl.onValueChanged.AddListener(delegate { ... })
```